# How do I make my bottom navbar stick to my top navbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two navbars. The top navbar sticks to the top of the page when the user scrolls down. When the user logs in, the bottom navbar becomes visible. But the bottom navbar is not sticky and disappears when scrolled down. How do I make the bottom navbar stick to the top navbar when scrolled down?

https://jsfiddle.net/Lance_Bitner/qqsx00sv/2/

```
.second_fixed_menu {
 border-color: rgba(91, 172, 220, 0.95);
 margin-top: 63px;
  }

.second_fixed_menu .sub_menu {
 float: right;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is one solution i found.

Remove your margin-top: 63px for .second-fixed-menu and add:

```
position: fixed;
top: 63px;
left: 0px;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add `position: fixed` to the bar:

```
.second_fixed_menu .sub_menu {
  position: fixed; /* add position fixed */
  width: 100%; /* set width to 100%*/
  text-align: right; /*add text align right*/
  /* float: right */ /*no need anymore this one */
}
```

```css
.navbar.innerpage {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: #1c5c82;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.res_title {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}
.second_fixed_menu {
  /*background-color: rgba(91, 172, 220, 0.95);*/
  border-color: rgba(91, 172, 220, 0.95);
  /*box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);*/
  margin-top: 63px;
}
.second_fixed_menu .sub_menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
.res_title {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}
.second_fixed_menu .sub_menu a {
  color: #fff;
  color: #1c5c82;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 16px;
  font-family: Assistant, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.sub_menu a.current {
  color: #0d2839;
}
.second_fixed_menu .sub_menu a:hover {
  /*   background: #e2e2e2 none repeat scroll 0 0;*/
  color: #2884ba;
}
.navbar.innerpage {
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-content">

  <div class="innerpage navbar w-nav" data-animation="over-right" data-collapse="medium" data-contain="1" data-doc-height="1" data-duration="400">

    <div class="w-container">

      <a class="brand w-nav-brand" href="">
        <img class="logo" src="">
      </a>

      <nav class="nav-menu w-nav-menu" role="navigation"><a class="nav-link w-nav-link" href="index.html" style="max-width: 940px;">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link w-nav-link" href="orientations.html" style="max-width: 940px;">Orientations</a>
        <a class="nav-link w-nav-link" href="profiles.html" style="max-width: 940px;">Profiles</a>
        <a class="nav-link w-nav-link " href="assessment.php" style="max-width: 940px;">Assessment</a>
        <a class="nav-link w-nav-link " href="join.html" style="max-width: 940px;">Join</a>
        <a class="nav-link w-nav-link" href="login.php" style="max-width: 940px;">Login</a>
      </nav>

      <div class="w-nav-button">

        <div class="menu-icon w-icon-nav-menu"></div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="w-nav-overlay" data-wf-ignore=""></div>

  </div>


  <div class="second_fixed_menu">



    <div class="w-container">



      <div class="sub_menu">



        <a href="result.php" class="current">RESULT</a>

        <a href="my_profile.php">USER PROFILE</a>

        <a href="http://198.1.111.21/~wwwlancebitner/demo1/blog/">BLOG</a>

        <a href="inform_research.php">INFORM RESEARCH</a>

        <a href="">LINK</a>



      </div>



    </div>





  </div>

  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
```